# parsing recurrence Google Calendar API

Tags: python, google-calendar-api, rrule

I'm trying to create small web app which will work with user Google Calendar data. Everything works fine except **getting start datetime** for events with **'recurrence'** in item.keys().

**Question**: How can I get start time of event from given data:

```
{'kind': 'calendar#event', 
'sequence': 0, 
'htmlLink': 'link', 
'creator': {my info}, 
'location': '...', 
'summary': '...', 
'etag': '"etag"', 
'organizer': {org_info}, 
'status': 'confirmed', 
'reminders': {'useDefault': True}, 
'created': '2016-09-18T07:02:56.000Z', 
'id': event_id, 
'iCalUID': 'iCalUID', 
'start': {'timeZone': 'Europe/Moscow', 'dateTime': '2016-09-07T14:35:00+03:00'}, 
'updated': '2016-09-18T07:02:56.612Z', 
'description': '...', 
'recurrence': ['RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;WKST=SU;INTERVAL=2;BYDAY=WE'], 
'end': {'timeZone': 'Europe/Moscow', 'dateTime': '2016-09-07T16:10:00+03:00'}}
```

My idea was to parse somehow RRULE, I've found way to get list of datetimes from it, but how to get *this* event start time is still question for me.

I'm getting data with `service.events().list(...).execute()`

I know that in the *new* API (i found this only today) item has nice called `originStartTime`, but old events don't have thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

StackOverflow magic: I was trying to find solution for 2 days, only after posting the question I've found method or function which does exactly what I needed [events().instances()](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/instances)